# How to replace mySQL by MS-SQL in datacenter

Tags: mysql, sql-server, oracle, replace

We are facing a challenge in the company.
We have an existing service running for a client and the hardware is in their permises. We are using mySQL as database. The service is some voice based stuff as we are a telecom company...
Now, the client has new policy stating that suppliers should no more use mySQL and instead will use MS-SQL or Oracle... inside their datacenter. Switching to another database is simply impossible for us now due to all development efforts and time.

My question is, do you have any idea of how we could manage the situation?

Kindly.

Comment: Well, if you can't talk the customer out of it, it seems to me that you're facing either losing the customer or a major rewrite of the app. There is Microsoft SQL Server Migration Assistant v5.3 for MySQL tool which could help in migrating the database.

Comment: Yes, but still we'll need to develop all the applications again. We can't afford that.
Is it possible to setup a kind of VON with an external close datacenter and store data remotely? Something like that? I don't know...

Comment: I see your point, and I know that this all very much depends on the architecture of the application.. Tell the customer it would be cheaper for them to pay you for the rewrite than to buy another application, train the people, customize it etc. (my guess is thay already know that).

Comment: why would it be a major rewrite? what are you using to connect to MySQL?